# Searching for a specific string token in a collection

Tags: c#

I've got a list of `Setting` objects with the following structure:

```
 public class Setting
 {
      int SettingID;
      string UserIDList;
 }
```

The `UserIDList` property stores user ID lists as comma delimited values, e.g. "32,45,22,53", where user IDs can exist in more than one object. Now supposing I want to search the entire collection for any objects that contain a specific user ID ("45" for example), what would be the most efficient way to do this?

I briefly considered iterating over the list, splitting `UserIDList` and then doing comparisons there, but this seems inefficient to me. I get the feeling that there may be a better way to do this. **Unfortunately, changing the structure of the object is out of the question**. What do you think?

Comment: Efficient/inefficient in which scenario? 1000 items on a desktop machine for an action triggered once by user from UI where data comes from a non local database? Write what it's more readable (see answers) and easy...

Comment: I'd suggest changing `Setting` to store the `UserIDList` as a `List<int>` if possible.

Comment: User regular expression

Comment: @RAJ it's brother suggestion of _use jQuery_! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with Linq :

```
var result = from setting in settingList
             where setting.UserIdList.Split(',').Contains("45")
             select setting;
```

Comment: The "Contains" method acts on a list and not on a string. List.Contains("45") tests if an element of the list is equal to "45". Thus, if the string contains "457", it will not be taken.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a regular expression.

```
List<Setting> FindItemsInList(List<Setting> settings, string val)
{
    var result = new List<Setting>();
    var searchRegEx = new RegEx(@"\b" + val + @"\b");
    foreach (var s in settings)
    {
        if (searchRegEx.IsMatch(s.UserIDList))
        {
            result.Add(s);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The idea here is that the regular expression uses the `\b` metacharacter to get whole words only. The regular expression created is of the form `"\b45\b".

This correctly handles cases where the value is at the start of the string, at the end of the string, and anywhere in the middle, and it won't erroneously tell you that "457" matches "45".

You can shorten that with LINQ. Replace the loop with:

```
var result = settings.Where(s => searchRegEx.IsMatch(s.UserIDList)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
settingList.Where(s => s.UserIDList == "45" ||
                       s.UserIDList.StartsWith("45,") || //LIKE('45,%')
                       s.UserIDList.EndsWith(",45") ||   //LIKE('%,45')
                       s.UserIDList.Contains(",45,"))    //LIKE('%,45,%')
```